# iPod Touch, HD video app Dim Screen?

Tags: applications, ipod-touch, video

Is there an app that will record HD video but sleep or dim the screen? The camera app that comes with the device chews through battery power like crazy.

Answer (score -1):

You can use backgrounder iPhone tweak if jailbroken that will run apps in background While iPhone seems to be shut down I use this when downloading long files I just turn on backgrounder to have app run in background  and press button on top of iPhone so everthing is off but what your running in background